# Linked List in C: What happens when we assign the current node to a temporary node pointer?

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have been given a task to write a function to reverse a doubly-linked list. I wrote the function and named it `reverse()`. The function is given below:

```
struct node* reverse(struct node** head_ref){
    struct node *current=*head_ref;
    struct node *tempNode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(current->next == NULL){
        return current;
    }
    while(current->next != NULL){
        //tempNode=current;
        tempNode->key=current->key;
        tempNode->data=current->data;
        tempNode->next=current->next;
        tempNode->prev=current->prev;
        current->next=current->prev;
        current->prev=tempNode->next;
        current=tempNode->next;
    }
    current->next=current->prev;
    current->prev=NULL;
    *head_ref =current;
    return current;
}
```

Where the `struct node** head_ref` parameter takes the reference of the head node `&head` as an argument. The function works fine. But my question here is instead of doing

```
tempNode->key=current->key;
tempNode->data=current->data;
tempNode->next=current->next;
tempNode->prev=current->prev;
```

Why can't I just do `tempNode=current;`?
When I try doing that instead my function doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: To increase your understanding of the problem you should learn how to debug code and how to inspect all variables during a debug session. You could use Visual Studio for example.

Comment: it is because if you do tempnode=current, then it wont create a new copy of node in temp, instead tempnode will  just point to the current

Comment: Well, if you are looking for a one liner, you could look into `memcpy()`.

Comment: Note that you really don't need to set `tempNode->key` or `tempNode->data`; you leave those fields in the current node alone.  However, if you did structure assignment (`*tempNode = *current;`) rather than pointer assignment (`tempNode = current;`), you would be OK.  Note that your code leaks a node every time the list is reversed; you don't free the `tempNode` that you allocate.  It would be better not to use `malloc()` for such a small structure; simply use `struct node tempNode;` and then `tempNode = *current;` and reference members by `tempNode.next` etc.  There's then no need to free it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments and answers. I wrote this code as a part of a coding challenge and I needed to do it in 30 minutes. Apologies for the lack of efficiency and abundance of redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

`tempnode = current` assign pointer, it means that both tempnode and currect would be pointing to the same address in memory.

```
tempnode = curr; // tempnode = 1036;

  1020   1028   1036   1044
+------+------+------+------+
|      |      | curr |      |
+------+------+------+------+
                 ^
                 |
tempnode ---------
```

You just need tempnode to have same values so you have to do `deep copy`, its what exactly you are doing.

```
tempNode->key=current->key;
tempNode->data=current->data;
tempNode->next=current->next;         // You just copy the content of node
tempNode->prev=current->prev;         // But they are in another part of memory

  120    ....   1028   1036   1044
+------+------+------+------+------+
| temp |      | curr |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

They have same values but they are pointing to another address.

I can see you are overwiting some pointers, you shouldnt do it becouse you are loosing address of allocated memory -> you cant free it anymore.

Store to some temp variable and after you remove it from node, you can free that memory.

Comment: Correct on the diagnosis of the problem.  There are refinements that could be made to the prescription for solving it.  (See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686130/linked-list-in-c-what-happens-when-we-assign-the-current-node-to-a-temporary-no#comment78331766_45686130) for some of the ideas.)

Comment: Thank you for advice, iam not very expirienced in giving answers. What should i also add to my answer? EDIT: Ah ill take a look thanks

Comment: I see you did mention the freeing problem, which I'd not noticed before (not noticed in your answer; as my comment shows, I did see it in the question).  I would probably have taken the code and produced new code that worked as expected, pointing out the various changes.  I'd have fleshed it out into an MCVE (and probably made a reference to the fact, linking to the [MCVE] page — which has a shorthand in comments but not in answers).  And I'd have added code to create the list, to print the list (to demonstrate that it worked), and to free the list (so I could claim Valgrind was OK with it).

Comment: Given that there's really no need to copy the key and data, I'd probably use `struct node *old_next = current->next;` and `struct node *old_prev = current->prev;` and then flip the links: `current->prev = old_next; current->next = old_prev; current = old_next;`.  I've not verified that would work, but something along those lines would.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advices. Just one thing. Everytime i did what you have mentioned, wrote correct code for OP, somebody DVed my answer, and wrote that SO isnt "give me the code".

Comment: That's unfair of people. A question like this is *not* a gimmedacodez question; they've made an honest effort at writing a solution, run into a stumbling block, and explained what their problem is. It is perfectly legitimate to help someone who's done all that. When there's no code in the question, or the code isn't an honest attempt at an answer (I saw one recently which contained the 'code' `int main(int argc, char **argv) { … }` (the … was a blank line) and the comment "I'm not sure where to go from here"), then writing the code is not appropriate. There are DVers who don't care about this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you really don't need to set `tempNode->key` or `tempNode->data`; you leave those fields in the current node alone. However, if you did structure assignment (`*tempNode = *current;`) rather than pointer assignment (`tempNode = current;`), you would be OK.

Note that your code leaks a node every time the list is reversed; you don't free the `tempNode` that you allocate (probably because you've overwritten the allocated space with the pointer assignment). It would be better not to use `malloc()` for such a small structure; simply use `struct node tempNode;` and then `tempNode = *current;` and reference members by `tempNode.next` etc. There's then no need to free it.

In fact, given that there's really no need to copy the key and data, I'd probably use `struct node *old_next = current->next;` and `struct node *old_prev = current->prev;` and then flip the links: `current->prev = old_next; current->next = old_prev; current = old_next;`, as in the code shown.  Keeping track of `old_curr` so that the correct value can be 'returned' (assigned to the pointer in the calling code via `head_ref`) is the other wrinkle in this code.  Note that it manages to avoid special-casing the empty list and the one-entry list.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int key;
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};

static struct node *reverse(struct node **head_ref)
{
    struct node *current = *head_ref;
    struct node *old_curr = 0;
    while (current != 0)
    {
        struct node *old_next = current->next;
        struct node *old_prev = current->prev;
        current->prev = old_next;
        current->next = old_prev;
        old_curr = current;
        current = old_next;
    }
    *head_ref = old_curr;
    return current;
}

static struct node *create(int key, int data)
{
    struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if (p != 0)
    {
        p->key = key;
        p->data = data;
        p->next = 0;
        p->prev = 0;
    }
    return p;
}

static struct node *insert_head(struct node *head, int key, int data)
{
    struct node *n = create(key, data);
    assert(n != 0);
    if (head != 0)
        head->prev = n;
    n->next = head;
    return n;
}

static void print_list(const char *tag, struct node *head)
{
    printf("%s: [", tag);
    const char *pad = "";
    while (head != 0)
    {
        printf("%s(%d => %d)", pad, head->key, head->data);
        pad = ",";
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

static void free_list(struct node *head)
{
    while (head != 0)
    {
        struct node *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int size = 0; size < 10; size++)
    {
        struct node *list = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            list = insert_head(list, i, (7 * i + 4 + size) % 10);
        print_list("New list", list);
        reverse(&list);
        print_list("Rev list", list);
        free_list(list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run, the program produces the output:

```
New list: []
Rev list: []
New list: [(0 => 5)]
Rev list: [(0 => 5)]
New list: [(1 => 3),(0 => 6)]
Rev list: [(0 => 6),(1 => 3)]
New list: [(2 => 1),(1 => 4),(0 => 7)]
Rev list: [(0 => 7),(1 => 4),(2 => 1)]
New list: [(3 => 9),(2 => 2),(1 => 5),(0 => 8)]
Rev list: [(0 => 8),(1 => 5),(2 => 2),(3 => 9)]
New list: [(4 => 7),(3 => 0),(2 => 3),(1 => 6),(0 => 9)]
Rev list: [(0 => 9),(1 => 6),(2 => 3),(3 => 0),(4 => 7)]
New list: [(5 => 5),(4 => 8),(3 => 1),(2 => 4),(1 => 7),(0 => 0)]
Rev list: [(0 => 0),(1 => 7),(2 => 4),(3 => 1),(4 => 8),(5 => 5)]
New list: [(6 => 3),(5 => 6),(4 => 9),(3 => 2),(2 => 5),(1 => 8),(0 => 1)]
Rev list: [(0 => 1),(1 => 8),(2 => 5),(3 => 2),(4 => 9),(5 => 6),(6 => 3)]
New list: [(7 => 1),(6 => 4),(5 => 7),(4 => 0),(3 => 3),(2 => 6),(1 => 9),(0 => 2)]
Rev list: [(0 => 2),(1 => 9),(2 => 6),(3 => 3),(4 => 0),(5 => 7),(6 => 4),(7 => 1)]
New list: [(8 => 9),(7 => 2),(6 => 5),(5 => 8),(4 => 1),(3 => 4),(2 => 7),(1 => 0),(0 => 3)]
Rev list: [(0 => 3),(1 => 0),(2 => 7),(3 => 4),(4 => 1),(5 => 8),(6 => 5),(7 => 2),(8 => 9)]
```

Note that I had to create 34 lines of support code for a 16-line function.  Granted, it wasn't all that hard, but an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) would have provided that infrastructure so I didn't have to do it.  Please remember to create an MCVE in future.